# Best approach to optimize a record history database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, optimization, history

I have a database that keeps record history. For each update to a record, the system will "deactivate" the previous record (along with all it's children), by setting the "Status" column to "0".

Now it's not a problem yet...but eventually this system is going to have a lot of records, and history is more important than speed right now. But the more records inserted, the slower searches become.

What is the best approach to archive the records? I've had suggestions to create a cloned archive database to hold the data. I've also had the idea to storing all previous records into a xml file, that can be read / loaded later if we need to dig up archived records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a separate partition containing only the active record if your DBMS supports it.  You can also add an index to Status so that the select ... from tbl where status=1 isn't incredibly slow.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187802.aspx