# What is the best way to record the edit history in a database

Tags: database, database-design, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am developing a system with Java EE and JPA where users can make changes to entities. It is needed to trace back to the changes when needed. So the all the changes and the user have to be recorded for each occasion when en update is made. What is the best way to record the changes.

For example, there is an Entity called Investigation. It has attributes like Name, Category, Price, Volume, etc. A user can search a single investigation and change the name in one instance and in another instance, another user can change the price. All these occasions with the change done and the user who did it is needed to be traced back when needed.

One method described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631959/best-approach-to-optimize-a-record-history-database) is that to label objects as old edited and create a new object with updated values, but the problem there are several other objects from different entities referring to the old one.

Another method as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749019/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-changes-history-to-database-fields) is to use a versioning field in a new table. Than can be achieved in JPA by creating a new entity that extends the main entity.

Out of these methods what is the best practice? Is there any other optimized way to keep the record editing history in Java Persistence?

Comment: borderline: "This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question **will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink supports history.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Hibernate, [Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) might be interesting for you. It performs auditing automatically, optionally appending metadata like current user.

For each audited entity it creates a history table that holds previous versions.